# Brightway2 not being imported in the Jupyterhub Docker

Tags: python, docker, jupyterhub, brightway

I am using JupyterHub deployed on a server. I installed the brightway2 using conda outside the container. Now when I try to import Brightway2 in the Jupyter notebook (on the JupyterHub server) the import fails showing no module named brightway2. I was just wondering how can I install BW2 inside the container or something else is the error here.

I am a beginner in computer sciences, therefore please excuse if the question is too basic, still help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you run jupyter hub on the environment where you installed this library? Did you try to restart the notebook?

Comment: I installed this library outside the docker container i.e. using powershell. However when I execute the docker image I am not able to run even the conda command, I believe this library has to be installed inside the container, however when I use the conda command to install it I get the following error "bash: conda: command not found"

Comment: the package needs to be inside the docker image otherwise you will not be able to access it. You should create a docker file that builds your image with the required dependancy. Miniconda offers a base image here: https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda/tags